# Horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have this code:

```
<style>
body {
background-color: yellow;
width: 100%;
}
h1 {
color: red;
font-size: 50px;
}
p {
font-size: 20px;
}
</style>

<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Content</p>
```

All my code should fit into a single HTML page, however a horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom of the page. Any help? Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Content</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the body width bit. It isn't needed, and browsers by default add a little bit on to the edge, meaning that it will be over `100%` so you will have to have a horizontal scroll bar.

Remove:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin:0` to the `body` rule. You've set `body` to take up 100% of the window width, but the margin isn't considered part of the width measurement so it's slightly bigger than the window. Use `padding` if you want to have some space around the content.

For more on this, read about the CSS box model.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `width:100%` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/oxngu3og/).

or you can keep the *width:100%* and add `margin:0`; to the body like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/oxngu3og/1/).